# Force .rb file running under specific ruby versions

Tags: ruby, version

I write a ruby script in a `.rb` file. It uses latest Ruby features (version 2.7). Is there any way to force this `.rb` file can only be executed in a specific Ruby version range? For example, the first line of a `.rb` file could be:

```ruby
#! ruby 2.7+
# This .rb file can only be run with Ruby version 2.7 or above
```

Comment: You can do this in your `Gemfile` if you have one using the `ruby` directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the gem [semantic](https://github.com/jlindsey/semantic) to handle parsing the current Ruby version:

```
require 'semantic'

# Require >= 2.7 < 3
exit unless Semantic::Version.new(RUBY_VERSION).satisfies?('~> 2.7')

# Require >= 2.7, including 3 and above
exit unless Semantic::Version.new(RUBY_VERSION).satisfies?('>= 2.7')
```

This requires you to use bundler and a Gemfile with your app.

Other comparators are listed in [the source code for the gem](https://github.com/jlindsey/semantic/blob/54de37b2ccd5e948b15f2fcfbd884eaac5f45967/lib/semantic/version.rb#L104-L110):

```
if ['<', '>', '<=', '>='].include?(comparator)
  satisfies_comparator? comparator, pad_version_string(other_version_string)
elsif comparator == '~>'
  pessimistic_match? other_version_string
else
  tilde_matches? other_version_string
end
```

This will allow you to fine-tune your version requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Naively,

```
unless RUBY_VERSION[0, 3] == "2.7"
  puts "You need 2.7")
  exit
end
```

Comment: Careful as that might detect `2.2.7`. Consider: `start_with?('2.7')`

Comment: Right, thanks, I overlooked that and edited my answer. Unfortunately `start_with` is an in ActiveSupport method.

Comment: Ruby, not Rails, has `String#start_with`, see: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F

Comment: But if they're not on 2.7, this will return `NoMethodError`; in that sense, they could rescue from it though :)

Comment: What makes you think `start_with` is only available in 2.7? I stopped checking earlier than [1.8.7](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F). Also, your answer has a syntax error. (unopened parentheses, which aren't typically used by the Rubyist with calls to `puts`)